# Download de Arquivos por link web C#

Tags: c#, web-service, visual-studio, download

gostaria de implantar em um sistema que estou fazendo uma opção de baixar os arquivos pela web, por links de nuvens pré definidas que eu tenho.

Porém não estou conseguindo fazer essa implementação. 
Podem me ajudar??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usando o método [WebClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe.aspx) é possível fazer isso de forma simples. Segue um exemplo:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
 {
         client.DownloadFile("http://exemplo.com/arquivo/foto/foto1.jpg", "foto1.jpg");
 }
```

Comment: desta forma como direciono a pasta em que o arquivo será salvo?

Comment: No parâmetro que define o nome do arquivo pode ser passado o caminho destino: `@"c:\foto.jpg"`

Comment: funcionou amigo, muito obrigado